# Update UserControl when parent item is changed

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the proper way (MVVM) to handle following situation? We have an window/user control which hosts few user controls and grid. When we select grid item, `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` is updating `SelectedAccount` property on user controls

```
<TabItem Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Basic}">
    <DockPanel>
       <accounts:UCBasic x:Name="UCBasic" SelectedAccount="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=gridMain}"></accounts:UCBasic>
    </DockPanel>
</TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="{x:Static p:Resources.AdditionalData}">
    <DockPanel>
          <accounts:UCAdditionalData x:Name="UCAdditionalData" SelectedAccount="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=gridMain}"></accounts:UCAdditionalData >
    </DockPanel>
    ... more user controls ...
</TabItem>
```

using their `DependencyProperty`. Now, how would I write PageModel for above user controls (`UCBasic, UCAdditionalData`) so they can load/show more data depending on `SelectedAccount` from grid. There is dirty way of using property changed event but I don't think it should be done that way. Each user control has this:

```
public Account SelectedAccount
{
    get { return (Account)GetValue(SelectedAccountProp); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(SelectedAccountProp, value);
    }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedAccountProp = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedAccount", typeof(Account), typeof(UCBasic));
```

Essentialy, how I would notify this user control that `SelectedAccount` value is changed and it should update itself (its own textboxes, grids and so on)?

Comment: Are you saying that your `SelectedAccount` doesn't work? Because if it does, you should be able to bind to properties of the `SelectedAccount` in the `UserControl`. Or do something in a property changed callback.

Answer (score 1):

if each user control  has `Account` property, it can do bindings in its own textboxes, grids and so on, e.g.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Account.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you can use INotifyPropertyChanged implementation in your ViewModel (if will send notification to update changed ViewModel property on View)
2) If you use one ViewModel for both user controls 1 option should help you immediately.
If you use different ViewModels you should update the secornd user control view model in code when the first user control is updated.